# ajax request - how to read the json obj

Tags: ajax, json

I am using ajax request and getting a json response. i do not how to read this

```
[{"systemReviewInfoMapListSize":1,
"diagnosis":"Impaired hearing\nEarache \nEar noise",
"isClinicalSummaryAvail":"false","isSymptom":"true",
"isDiagnosis":"true",
"symptom":"Impaired hearing\nEarache \nEar noise",
"isSystemReviewInfo":"true"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [Here](http://www.json.org/js.html)

Hope someone will clarify me why the downvote, not that it matters, I've always though SO was a community to enrich our knowledge about programming and not another code fragment repository.

Comment: This should be better a comment or at least, you should develop your answer by giving here (when and wether it's possible) the main facts or snippets of code that would answer the question

Comment: Maybe you're right, but what's the point of cut 'n pasting from a site / or from a script, when it's faster giving a link to an exhaustive answer ? Giving only code samples won't teach anything, IMHO is better learn how to discover informations by actually reading the docs, so pointing someone to proper docs is good.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're setting a variable as the ajax response?

if so you could do this:

```
var objJSON = ajax.response;

var systemReviewInfoMapListSize = objJSON.systemReviewInfoMapListSize;
var diagnosis = objJSON.diagnosis;
etc...
```

Hope that makes sense... basically your ajax response returns an object full of name:value pairs. You access the values within the json like you would access the properties of any other js object, by taking the variable storing the object and appending .PropertyName.